# How to print text from texfield in label on Viewcontroller.swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I am actually trying to print whatever text in textfield to be displayed in label which is `textDisplay` and `textf` being the textfield.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textf: UITextField!

@IBAction func enter(_ sender: Any) {
    textDisplay.isHidden = false
    textf.text = textDisplay.text
}
```

Comment: You've explained some of what you want to do which is a good start but haven't offered any hints about what the problem is. Does this code compile? Is your `enter` function being called, how do you know? What unexpected result do you see in your label? You appear to be setting the text of your `textf` text field equal to the text of your `textDisplay` label which doesn't seem to match "print whatever text in textfield to be displayed in label" but it's hard to know what you intended.

Comment: When i press the button it only prints lable and doesn't print what i have entered in the textfield

Comment: I'm sure that if you look carefully the second line of your enter function you'll see where is the problem. By the way, "enter" is not good name for function.

Comment: Okay i will change it then

Comment: I dont know what is wrong

Comment: i changed the IBAction func enter to IBAction func  hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to display textField's text in the label after pressing on the button, right? Make sure that you connect all @IBOutlet and @IBAction and then, let change to `textDisplay.text = textf.text`

Comment: So do i change it to IBAction into IBOutlet of the button

Comment: textDisplay and textf are IBOutlet, enter is IBAction

Comment: Yeah but i don't know how to connect these 2 elements

Comment: Let delete all these components and create again, drag a label, a textField and a button from Object library into your UI. Then, in ther storyboard, open Assistant Editor (View > Assistant Editor > Show...), hold control key and drag from the label to ViewController.swift, enter textDisplay for a name. Go on with textField (textf) and button. For button choose connection is IBAction instead of IBOutlet.

Comment: Label and textfield will be IBOutlet. Alright I will re-create it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I figured it out!